# Bhagvad gita 18 :66 , is surrender to krishna possible without leaving duties

Tags: krishna, gita

BG 18.66: ***Abandon all varieties of dharmas*** and simply surrender unto Me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

1. Now, everyone can't leave all duties but wants liberation from sinful reactions. Now if I can't leave my duty how do I surrender to krishna?
2. Also is there a way to know that you are completely surrendered or not?

Answer (score 2):

Please look into the surrounding verses than stand-alone verse.

> 18.61 The Supreme Lord dwells in the hearts of all living beings, O Arjun. According to their karmas, He directs the wanderings of the souls, who are seated on a machine made of material energy.
>
> 18.62 Surrender exclusively unto Him with your whole being, O Bharat. By His grace, you will attain perfect peace and an eternal abode.
>
> 18.63 Thus, I have explained to you this knowledge that is more secret than all secrets. Ponder over it deeply, and then do as you wish.
>
> 18.64 Hear again My supreme instruction, the most confidential of all knowledge. I am revealing this for your benefit because you are very dear to Me.
>
> 18.65 Always think of Me, be devoted to Me, worship Me, and offer obeisance to Me. Doing so, you will certainly come to Me. This is My pledge to you, for you are very dear to Me.
>
> 18.66 Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto Me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.

This is from [Swami Mukundananda's translation.](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/18)

The standalone verse would not make much sense than the verses around it. From 18.61 to 18.63, Krishna explains the existence of the supreme soul that is inside every human being - including you and me, along with a soul that directs our body. So, one should surrender one's soul to the supreme being inside our body and you'll attain perfect peace and eternal abode.

From verses 18.64-18.66: Krishna takes the oath of the responsibility of the Arjuna on the battlefield where he was scared and crying. He consoled him by saying that he should be devoted to him and he'll take care of Arjuna. By surrendering to Krishna, Arjuna will **NOT** abandon his duties on the battlefield, but follow Krishna's direction on the battlefield and fight (which he conveyed in the 2nd chapter).

Therefore, since the Arjuna was terrified and afraid of his duty as a warrier, Krishna simply consoled him by taking responsibility for the war and asking him to surrender his everything (including Dharma) to Krishna by following Krishna's direction on the battlefield.

This is exactly what he did in the rest of the verses of Mahabharata, where he fought and won later.

Answer (score 1):

If  **Abandon all varieties of dharmas**  could only mean , forsaking one's duties in order to surrender,.. then Lord Krishna would have agreed with  Arjunas persistence in resorting to asceticism by abandoning the war.. Nevertheless, abandoning the karma (Gita 3.3) applies to  those already in possession of  sense restraint (shama dhama etc)  ,who ve already succeeded in renunciation, befitting asceticism.Others must not abandon their obligatory duties in this world, rather should strive to perform them with the spirit of renunciation..In this way they surrender to Lord, by offering work in yog. **sva-karmaṇā tam abhyarchya siddhiṁ vindati mānavaḥ**,(18.46)

But the clause, that is crucial for 'getting liberation from all sinful reaction' is **Mam EKAM Sharanam vraja** , entitling an ascetic s surrender, bcos it is not possible for a normal to possess conviction on God/Self alone.

Gita states numerous litmustest (like Samaloshtashmakanchana 14.24) to determine who must abandon karma and meditate , and who must not.

In case of an non ascetic,
`way to know that you are completely surrendered or not`

> When the Lord declares, that He will liberate him from
> all sins, He means to say, that having taken refuge in Him, if
> he finds that he has not got rid of evil propensities, has not
> developed devotion to God, and has not beheld Him, he need
> not worry. It is the Lord's responsibility, to free him from all
> defects. If he himself wanted to shoulder the responsibility, it
> shows that he has not yet taken refuge. When he has taken
> refuge in Him, **he should be free from worry, sadness, fear
> and doubt.**  If these evils, crop up in him, they will prove to be
> obstacles in refuge and the responsibility (burden) will remain
> his. This responsibility, is a blot on refuge. After he has taken
> refuge in Him, his shortcomings are the Lord's, and his whole
> responsibility, goes to the Lord.
> (Gita sadhak sanjivini, Swami Ramsukhdas)